# merge request api authorization issue

Tags: python, api, gitlab, postman

I am trying to fetch what are the available merge requests for my repository as mentioned in the [link](http://repositories.compbio.cs.cmu.edu/help/api/merge_requests.md#:%7E:text=To%20get%20all%20merge%20requests,the%20list%20of%20merge%20requests.). I have entered my user id and password when doing a get call ( see picture ). But the credentials entered are not considered and on output, it is showing a login page.
I am trying to add these APIs for my automatic report generation, like how many MR are open and closed this week and some details like who created it and who has made review comments.

Even I tried with curl command after creating a personalized access token

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: mQ7cszUHymhyEze9Y8BC" --header "Sudo: dka07" "https://myrepo/-/merge_requests"
```

I got a reply

```
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://mygitlab/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

Any help appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With your curl command, you could try using the -L option to automatically follow redirects.

[https://reqbin.com/req/c-bvijc9he/curl-follow-redirect#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20Curl%20does%20not,%2D%2Dlocation%20command%2Dline%20option](https://reqbin.com/req/c-bvijc9he/curl-follow-redirect#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20Curl%20does%20not,%2D%2Dlocation%20command%2Dline%20option).

Comment: adding - L is just parsing the whole page , it is not logging in.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not using the correct API endpoint and request format.

The [Authentication section of the API docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#authentication) explain how to authenticate. You would not use `sudo` unless you're impersonating another user, and generally we say that's easier with an impersonation token anyway.

Note: If the token you posted is a real one, please make sure to revoke it **immediately**, so that someone else can't use it.

While there are [Merge Request API docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html), they're not quite as helpful if what you're looking for is [how to build a REST API query](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#how-to-use-the-api).

Taking the information from the docs I've linked, what you want to do is make sure you're authenticating only with your Personal Access Token and `curl`ing the API endpoint (instead of the Web UI path).

For example:

`curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: mQ7cszUHymhyEze9Y8B" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/myrepo/merge_requests"`

If you're having issues with using the project path, I recommend using the project ID instead (`/projects/:id/merge_requests` -> `/projects/1234/merge_requests`).